# How to determine if Android App is installed from Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to detect if my app is installed from Google Play or not. I can use the API to detect the package name of the installer and say that my app is installed from GooglePlay if installer name is "com.android.vending".

Technically its possible to have Android device without Google services and the manufacturer has installer package name as "com.android.vending". How can I mitigate this risk? Is it safe to assume that "com.android.vending" is always Google Play? In my opinion, just checking installer package name is not sufficient.

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String)
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstallSourceInfo(java.lang.String)